# jQuery snippet don't work in my wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, css

I'm building my portfolio website over a wordpress theme. In the page "about me", i have made first in code pen. When i go to insert the code in my website, the jQuery effect don't work and i don't know what i must do.

The jQuery function is a "flip" effect when you click on "Currículo" button. How you can see here: http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/sAtvD

This flip effect don't work in my page: http://felipemartinin.com.br/acerca/

The jQuery src: http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/themes/FelipeMartinin/js/portfolio.js

If anyone can help me I'm really grateful.

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like there is a conflict here between jQuery and WordPress, try to put your code inside closure:

```
(function($){
    $('.goFlip').on("click", function(){
    $('.aboutMe').toggleClass('rotate-3d');
    $('.card-back').toggleClass('z-up');
    $('.card-back > .aboutHeader > h2').addClass('fadeInUp');
    $('.backContent-wrap .backContent').addClass('fadeInUp');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into your console when loading the page, you'll find, that it can't load a lot of plugins (thats the 404 not found error):

```
GET http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/css/captions.css?ver=3.8 404 (Not Found) felipemartinin.com.br/:37
GET http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css?ver=3.8 404 (Not Found) felipemartinin.com.br/:36
GET http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css?ver=3.8 404 (Not Found) felipemartinin.com.br/:46
GET http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js?ver=3.8 404 (Not Found) felipemartinin.com.br/:49
GET http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=3.8 404 (Not Found) felipemartinin.com.br/:50
GET http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.min.js?ver=2.0.20 404 (Not Found) (index):601
GET http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js?ver=2.60 404 (Not Found) (index):602
GET http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/woocommerce.min.js?ver=2.0.20 404 (Not Found) (index):609
GET http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.min.js?ver=2.0.20 404 (Not Found) (index):603
GET http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.min.js?ver=1.3.1 404 (Not Found) (index):610
GET http://felipemartinin.com.br/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/cart-fragments.min.js?ver=2.0.20 404 (Not Found)
```

First of all, you should avoid such errors. Then have a look, where the file lays on the server, and correct the paths.